# document.getElementById().innerHTML not working

Tags: javascript, html, jinja2

I am trying to display the first 15 results of my neural network on a web page. However, nothing is showing up on the screen even when I replace results with "HELLO" in the line document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = results;. I am not getting any errors from this code.

```
    <div id="results">  
    </div>
    <script>
        var n = 1;

        function display_res() {
            var results = "";
            for (var i = n; i < n + 15; i++) {
                results += ("<p class='metadata'>" + JSON.parse({{graph_NN}}['node" + i.toString() + "']['metadata']).toString() + "<span><button class='download' onclick='download()'>Download</button></span><span><button class='tune' onclick='finetune'>Fine-tune</button></span></p>");
            }
            n+=15;
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = results;
        }

        window.onload = display_res();

        function finetune() {
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "/finetune",
                data: {name: {{name}}}
            });
        }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change it to `window.onload = display_res;`
Function shouldn’t be called at onload but be registered.

Comment: I did this, but it still unfortunately did not fix this problem.